# JOLT to index a field based on the name of another

Tags: jolt

Not sure if this is possible in jolt.
We are trying to extract a value whose field name is indexed by another field. Please take a look at the description below.

```
{
  "_src" : {
    "SomeName" : 123,
    "FName" : "SomeName"
  }
}
```

to

```
{
  "val": "123",
  "_src" : {
    "SomeName" : 123,
    "FName" : "SomeName"
  }
}
```

Any ideas on how approach this, or if this is even possible in JOLT?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using shift spec:

1. Match on `_src`
2. Set `value` using `SomeName`
3. Using syntax `@(1,src)` which means go up 1 level and copy src, `&` will get the name of the current element.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "_src": {
        "SomeName": "val",
        "@(1,_src)": "&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```